# Updating records in SQL Server database using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to ASP.NET, I am facing some difficulty in updating records inside database in ASP.NET. My code is showing no errors, but still the records are not being updated. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Code behind is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {    
        con.Open();
        string query = "Select * from Customers where UserName ='" + Session["user"] + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            txt_name.Text = reader["CustName"].ToString();
            txt_phonenumber.Text = reader["Contact"].ToString();
            txt_address.Text = reader["CustAddress"].ToString();
            txt_cardnum.Text = reader["CustAccountNo"].ToString();
            txt_city.Text = reader["CustCity"].ToString();
            txt_emailaddress.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
            txt_postalcode.Text = reader["CustPOBox"].ToString();
            Cnic.Text = reader["CustCNIC"].ToString();    
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}

protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd2 = con.CreateCommand();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.CommandText = "Select CustID from Customers where UserName = '" + Session["user"] + "'";
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());

    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd2.CommandText = "update Customers set CustName='" + txt_name.Text + "',CustCNIC='" + Cnic.Text + "',Email='" + txt_emailaddress.Text +  "',CustAccountNo='" + txt_cardnum.Text + "',CustAddress='" + txt_address.Text + "',CustPOBox='" + txt_postalcode.Text + "' where CustID='" + id + "'";
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}
```

Help will be much appreciated. THANKS!

After debugging the result i am getting is this

> ```
>   cmd2.CommandText    "update Customers set CustName='Umer Farooq',CustCNIC='42101555555555',Email='adada@gmail.com',CustAccountNo='0',CustAddress='',CustPOBox='0' where CustID='6'" string
> ```

Here Account Number And POBOX is 0 and address is going as empty string. But i have filled the text fields

Comment: Your update statement where the id is supplied is being surrounded by single quote which read CustID='id'. This means sql might be reading it as a string.

Comment: Does the `int id` variable get populated correctly from that Select statement?

Comment: It is not making any difference @jmag

Comment: @NicholasV. yes it is.

Comment: Why don't you get the `CustID` from your first `Select`?

Comment: Try debugging and getting the SQL that is generated then running that in your db. Also in general [don't use string concatenation for queries](http://bobby-tables.com/about).

Comment: @WEI_DBA what i am trying to do here is to show the previous record which has to be updated in the textbox in page load method.
When user after changing the information hits update button, updated values should enter in the db. 

Problem im facing is that when the update query executes, some of the values are null. I dont know why this is happening. although i have filled all the text boxes

Comment: What is saved inside the Session["user"]?

Comment: @jmag unique usename is saved inside the session["user"]

Comment: Try casting it back to string. Session["user"].ToString().

Comment: @jmag nothing changed :|

Comment: Did you do what @AhsanHasan recommended? Take your query and execute in the DB. How does that go?

Comment: @NicholasV. it is working fine there

Comment: Use breakpoint and step into your code line one by one using F11. Hover over the strings to confirm they are what they are needed to be.  If the error is from SQL side it will just stop running.  That would mean the command string is wrong.

Comment: @jmag i did that,  when the update query executes, some of the values are (empty string). I dont know why this is happening. although i have filled all the text boxes

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: That means the GET part is working. The error is coming from the btnSubmit Event where the update takes place. check the value of int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()); If its null, means "Select CustID from Customers where UserName = '" + Session["user"] + "'"; is not functioning well.

Comment: @jmag i have checked it as well, im getting the correct id there.

Comment: Can you verify your connection string is for the right db?

Comment: @fqhv it is the right db

Comment: And you 100% debugged it, copied the generated CommandText, and ran that in the db without any errors?

Comment: How many postbacks occurs when you click BtnSubmit??

Comment: @fqhv i have edited my post and entered the commandText there . Kindly look into that

Comment: @jmag  i have edited my post and entered the commandText there . Kindly look into that

Comment: Can you go to your server explorer, right-click on the table you are trying to update and select new query. From there paste the commandtext and execute the statement. That will give you a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: @jmag Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '" + id + "' to data type int. this is what im getting there

Comment: As what @jmag said in his first comment. Remove the single quotes from around the `id`. So it should look like `CustID=6`

Comment: @WEI_DBA i am sorry but it is not solving my issue. Thank you for all the concerns guys but :|

Comment: On the `Update` statement. The `Where` clause should look like `"' where CustID=" + id + ""` Look at answer below. It is more organized and easier to understand.

Comment: @WEI_DBA :  "update Customers set CustName='" + txt_name.Text + "',CustCNIC='" + Cnic.Text + "',Email='" + txt_emailaddress.Text +  "',CustAccountNo='" + txt_cardnum.Text + "',CustAddress='" + txt_address.Text + "',CustPOBox='" + txt_postalcode.Text + "' where CustID=" + id + "";

This is what i have here now, but it is still not working !!!!

Comment: Do you still get an error when you copy the text into a new query window and run it?

Comment: now it says : Error converting data type varchar to bigint. @WEI_DBA

Comment: What has a datatype of `bigint` in your table? Can you show the schema of the table you are trying to update the data? By looking at the names it could be `CustCNIC` or `CustAccountNo`.

Comment: Change this line ----int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()); into  ---int id =(Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar(); As MSDN suggests. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WEI_DBA exactly CNIC and AccountNo are BigInt

Comment: Remove the single quotes around those as well.

Comment: You are directly assigning text values from TextBox into your table with no proper conversion. I assume that there validators in place to check if they are empty, otherwise there will be more problems that will arise.

Comment: @WEI_DBA after removing them im getting exception 

 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: The single quotes around `BIGINT` fields should have no affect as long as the value can be cast to a `BIGINT`. Does your table have any triggers?

Comment: I dont understand why i am getting 0 in account number and Cnic. I am also getting an empty string in address field. although i am filling those text fields

Comment: @fqhv there are no triggers

Comment: Can you check how many postbacks that are occurring when you click BtnSubmit??

Comment: strange thing happened. I comment out the code written in my page load method that is retrieving the current values in text field. I ran the code and it worked fine. Records are updating correctly. @jmag

Comment: BtnSubmit does a postback and runs the code in the page load before running the code in the BtnSubmit event. If you still want the code in the page load, wrap them in If(!IsPostBack){//the codes from page load}. This will prevent it from firing during the BtnSubmit event.

Comment: @jmag Why do you think this would interrupt the `UPDATE`?

Comment: @jmag thanks alot that solved my problem. Thank you for tolerating me for so long :)

Comment: Thank You everyone you guys are great ^_^

Comment: @fghv It does not interrupt the update, instead it pulls data from database and replaces the values of the textbox before update gets fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When BtnSubmit fires the event, the code in the Page_Load runs before the codes in BtnSubmit, replacing the values placed in the TextBox with the values from the Database before the Update takes place.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do to fix this is to use good ADO techniques, using `SqlParameters` for the passed in values; and not the risky **SQL Injection** method of concatenating strings together.

This first portion does just that. I have added in the `int sqlRA` variable to read the results of the non-query, which will return Rows Affected by the query. This is wrapped in a simple `try...catch` routine to set the value to negative 1 on any error. Other error handling is up to you. That makes your code look something like this:

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionUser", Session["User"]);
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());

cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET CustName = @CustName, CustCNIC = @CustCNIC, Email =  @Email, CustAccountNo = @CustAccountNo, CustAddress = @CustAddress, CustPOBox = @CustPOBox WHERE (CustID = @CustID)";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", txt_name.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustCNIC", Cnic.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txt_emailaddress.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAccountNo", txt_cardnum.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAddress", txt_address.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustPOBox", txt_postalcode.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", id);

int sqlRA
try { sqlRA  = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
catch (Exception ex) {
    sqlRA = -1;
    // your error handling
}

/* sqlRA values explained
    -1 : Error occurred
     0 : Record not found
     1 : 1 Record updated
    >1 :Multiple records updated
*/
```

Now reading through your code, all we are doing with the first query is mapping the Session["User"] to id, and then using that id in the second query to do the update, and that Username is not updated in the second. Waste of a query most likely, as we could use the Session["User"] to do the update. That will bring you down to this query, and still bring back that Rows Affected value back:

```
cmd0.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd0.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET CustName = @CustName, CustCNIC = @CustCNIC, Email =  @Email, CustAccountNo = @CustAccountNo, CustAddress = @CustAddress, CustPOBox = @CustPOBox WHERE (UserName = @SessionUser)";
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", txt_name.Text);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustCNIC", Cnic.Text);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txt_emailaddress.Text);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAccountNo", txt_cardnum.Text);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAddress", txt_address.Text);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustPOBox", txt_postalcode.Text);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionUser", Session["User"]);


int sqlRA
try { sqlRA  = cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
catch (Exception ex) {
    sqlRA = -1;
    // your error handling
}

/* sqlRA values explained
    -1 : Error occurred
     0 : Record not found
     1 : 1 Record updated
    >1 :Multiple records updated
*/
```